# Can we change the jQuery package version in Bower.json

Tags: jquery, bower

In a preexisting application, I have bower.json file containing jQuery version 2.1.3. And I have been assigned the task to change it to the latest version. I haven't worked with bower before but I just learned that it helps installing right version of the package and their dependencies.

Is it as simple as changing the version in the above manifest file? What else would I have to do to so that from then on, the application runs with the mentioned latest version(in manifest) of jQuery?

Comment: What about just running `bower update jquery --force-latest`?

Comment: Could you please point me out the steps that needs to be performed or share the link. I want a link or something that briefly fulfill my requirement at hand for now I don't have much time to go into every detail

Comment: Open bash, `cd` to your application's root directory, and then literally type that command in and hit enter. That will update your jQuery in the project to the latest version. I don't understand how this can be so difficult that you are compelled to complain you don't want to "go into every detail". Unbelievable.

Comment: To list the current version of the packages I typed 'PM> bower list' in Package Manager Console (in VS) but it didn't show any, instead displayed the path to my project. How could i find the version?

Comment: I ran command "bower update jquery" on Package Manager Console but it gives error: bower                          ENOTINS Package jquery is not installed. Although I chose the Default Project to be the one containing bower.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case I had old version of GIT as I was using VS 2013 - and the latest version for GIT came with VS 2017 - so I had to explicitly update the version of GIT and had to remove the older version from Control Panel for the command to work without error.

Command: bower update jquery

[image]